# Woocommerce emails adds a <br>

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I am trying to find a way to get rid of extra < br > in woocommerce emails. It adds < br > in after Request and also in the date:[image]

```
         <h2>
         <a class="link" href="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'post.php?post=' . $order->get_id() . '&action=edit' ) ); ?>">
          <b><?php  printf(__( 'Request #%s test', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_order_number() ); ?></b>
          </a> 
           (<?php  strip_tags(
              printf( '<time datetime="%s">%s</time>', 
                  $order->get_date_created()->format( 'c' ), 
                wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ), 
                '<br>' ); 
            ?>)
         </h2>
```

Comment: What have you found so far?  What have you tried?  What is the code you are sharing? Can it be modified?

Comment: I have tried adding strip_tags( text, '<br >'); , but then it displays it completely wrong. I have also tried moving it around in the file

Comment: _What is the code that you are sharing above? Can it be  modified? **Where** did you add strip_tags? Moved *what* around in *which* file?_  Specifics matter!